# Control doesn't bind to SqlDataSource on page load with blank parameters

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

Suppose you have a SQLDataSource that looks like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqldsSample" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [col1], [col2] FROM [tbl] WHERE [col3] = @val) ORDER BY [col1] DESC;">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="False" Name="val" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="val2" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Just assume you have decided you want to declare the 'val2' parameter here and you don't want to bother with adding and/or removing parameters later in the code-behind (say, to change the SelectCommand to do some filtering with some extra criteria).

It will fail without an error - the control will just show up empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify a default value for the parameter even if it's not used. For example, just putting in a space character will work:

`<asp:Parameter DefaultValue=" " Name="val2" Type="String" />`

Note that it still won't work if you omit the DefaultValue property.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the `CancelSelectOnNullParameter` parameter on SqlDataSource - you need to set this to false if you expect any of your parameters to be null.

It's not very obvious and it has caught me out a few times!